# i18n find in associated models with rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization

I need to build a multi-language site, where the client will add records in many languages.
I wanna know if Rails has something to do a website like this. Imagine these scenario: I have a Post and Category. The user language sessions is set to en-US. When the user do a search for category 'car' the system will retrieve the Category model and all Posts TRANSLATED in that language.

Can I accomplish this with Rails 3?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by yourself by adding a translation table for the posts and categories tables and join them with the original tables. Alternatively, have a look at Globalize2: https://github.com/joshmh/globalize2 which does all the backend work for you.